# Can't add user attribute using Accounts.onCreateUser

Tags: javascript, meteor

I tried to add an attribute 'permission' to all newly created users. But it somehow doesn't work. I use this code to add the attribute

```
 Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user.permission = 'default';
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

But when I retrieve a user object on the client side I can't see the attribute

```
u = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId)
u.permission
>undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create it properly. The problem is that client does not see this value. Taken from [documentation:](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user)

> By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile

So you need to publish / subscribe for the additional fields.

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function() {
  if(!this.userId) return null;
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {
    permission: 1,
  }});
});
```

Client:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('userData');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId)` should be changed to `Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId())`.

Also, I'm not sure what fields on the user object that actually are transmitted to the client.  You might need to change`user.permission = 'default'` to `options.profile.permission = 'default'` so your `Accounts.onCreateUser` will look like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if(!options.profile){
       options.profile = {}
    }
    options.profile.permission = 'default'
    if (options.profile)
        user.profile = options.profile;
    return user;
});
```

Comment: If i try it your way i get this error:
`Cannot set property 'permission' of undefined`

Comment: It's not wise to add `permission` flag to `profile`, it is user-writeable!