# Custom fields on Meteor.users not being published

Tags: javascript, meteor

My end goal is to have `CUSTOM_FIELD_I_FREAKEN_WANT_TO_PUBLISH` available to templates via `{{currentUser}}` if they are logged in, but Meteor is not sending down all the fields from the users collection.

In Server:

```
Meteor.publish('userdata', function() {
    this.ready(); // do I really even need to do this?
    //return Meteor.users.find(); //This STILL doesn't work
    return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
});
```

In Client:

```
var s = Meteor.subscribe('userdata', function() { 
    console.log('userdata available');
    console.log('s.ready: '+s.ready())
});
console.log('s.ready: '+s.ready())
```

I can verify that there are fields in the collection by connecting to the mongo instance directly and typing: `db.users.find()`:

```
{
    "_id" : "N2M7Zp265vkbTBTFF",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2013-10-15T03:29:53.155Z"),
    "CUSTOM_FIELD_I_FREAKEN_WANT_TO_PUBLISH" : "P4GRrQMixEZducmuo",
    "profile" : {
        "name" : "Jonathan Dumaine",
            ...,
    },
    "services" : {
        "facebook" : {
            ....,
        }
    }
}
```

After verifying that the subscription is ready in the client, the only fields on the users collection are `_id` and `_profile`. The additional fields are not visible in the client (via console `Meteor.users.find().fetch()`) nor are they defined when accessed through templates.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17963849/876409)

---

> By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile

So you need to publish / subscribe for the additional fields.

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function() {
  if(!this.userId) return null;
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {
    permission: 1,
  }});
});
```

Client:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('userData');
});
```

---

Looking at your code, the missing part is autorun on subscription. Without it, the subscription is called once when the app is loaded and does not change when the user changes - when he is set for the first time, for example.

Comment: Oh that is a very good point, but in this case it still wouldn't work because there's nothing reactive in the publish function, no? It would have to be switched with Meteor.user() instead of this.userId. And if the reactivity is inside the publish function, isn't it not necessary to have subscribe inside an autorun? :|

Comment: I personnaly use this kind of solution (which is described in official meteor docs) and it works well for me.
If you need to update user information from client you will need to add Meteor.users.allow/deny

Comment: From the docs "However, if the logged-in user changes, the publish function is rerun with the new value." So this answer will work but some of the information is inaccurate.  The publish will rerun whenever the user changes so the client will get new data.  A one line publish and one line subscribe will work fine.

Answer (score 8):

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users):

> By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are published to the client.

So in order to publish your field, you will need to do something like:

```
Meteor.publish('userdata', function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'CUSTOM_FIELD_I_FREAKEN_WANT_TO_PUBLISH':1}});
});
```

Comment: I understood that line in the docs as "username, emails and profile are published by default, so any additional `publish`es would publish the rest of the fields". I figured `'userdata'` would be supplementary to the default `user` publishing since it references Meteor.users directly. Is that not the case?

Comment: Did you mean to remove the search criteria that limited the publish to the current user's data?

Answer (score 3):

You were very close.  You have two problems:

1) The ready() call in publish is unnecessary since it is sent automatically if you return a cursor.  When you do need it you want to call it at the end of the publish after all data is sent.

2) You want to return a cursor which is done with `find()` instead of `findOne()`.

So your publish would be:

```
//on server
Meteor.publish( 'userData', function(){
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

Your code shown does not actually test if any data has been received so to make sure that is not the problem try:

```
//on client
var s = Meteor.subscribe('userdata', function() { 
  console.log('userdata available');
  console.log('s.ready: '+s.ready());
  console.log('userData: ' + JSON.stringify( Meteor.users.findOne()) );
});

console.log('s.ready: '+s.ready())
```

Also, as David Weldon says in his answer, you would probably want to specify and limit exactly what fields get sent to the client by setting a fields option in the find() you publish.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you were probably trying to find function `Accounts.onCreateUser()` from docs http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser. There is exact example how to add any object into user doc, next to profile, email, _id, etc.