# Provide data for all routes with iron-router

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to figure out a way to publish data for every single route in my application. The accounts-ui-bootstrap3 package looks for a value called user_profile_picture, and if it's there, it will display an avatar image in the navbar. From what I can tell, in order for this to work, this information needs to be provided in an iron-router data hook. Now... if I provide this in every single route myself, it works fine. But that gets messy and tedious as more routes are added, so I'd like to be able to provide this value globally.

I tried making a global data hook inside the router's configure block (below), but I guess the data hook is only used by controllers.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'not_found',
  waitOn: function() { 
      return [
        subs.subscribe('notifications'),
        subs.subscribe('currentUser', {
          "_id": true,
          "email_hash": true,
          "user_profile_picture": true,
          "profile": true
        })
      ];  
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      user_profile_picture: Meteor.user().user_profile_picture
    };
  }
});
```

I also tried setting the data inside an onAfterAction and onBeforeAction hook, but I think this.data() is read only... or it at least it didn't add the property to it when I tried. I also tried

```
this.data().user_profile_picture = Meteor.user().user_profile_picture;
```

and

```
var data = this.data();    
data.user_profile_picture = Meteor.user().user_profile_picture;
this.data(data);
```

but these didn't work either. I'm not sure if it's possible to change the data like that, or if I just did it incorrectly.

I've searched there documentation, and there is mention of getData() and setData() methods, but the documentation must be outdated because those have since been removed.

Any ideas how to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could be completely off the mark here but have a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391308/custom-fields-on-meteor-users-not-being-published You will need to add the user_profile_picture to the list of fields published then I think you can just user {{currentUser.user_profile_picture}} in any template. Alternatively whichever template displays the avatar image create a helper for that template and it will work within that template regardless of route

Comment: You should probably also do the notifications subscription on application startup, instead of just re-subscribing on each route.

Comment: I have the profile image being published right now. If I look at the collection in the Chrome console the information is there.

I tried making a template helper in my main/root layout page called user_profile_picture that would simply return the URL, but the package's template didn't seem to recognize it. It tries to access it using the {{#with user_profile_picture}} helper, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I am using SubscriptionManager, so the subscriptions aren't re-done on each route change as far as know. I'll look into that anyways just to make sure.