# Meteor: what is the right way to add custom settings object to users collection?

Tags: collections, meteor, publish-subscribe

There are multiple examples on publish/subscribe but not clear on what is the best practice for storing custom data in the in-built "users" collection in Meteor (especially in the new possibility of template specific collections).

For example, I need to store user browse history - something that is accessible through `Meteor.user().settings.history.lastvisited[]`

The challenge is:

1. Is any special publish / subscribe required for the above? (the
   reason being, I am assuming the `users` collection is already
   published and available on client side - so do we need another?)
2. How to take care of edge cases where user is new and hence `settings.history` object may not be defined? Can we have a special publish that automatically takes care of creating an empty object if the `settings` is undefined? How to do it?

I did this :

```
// server side
Meteor.publish('userSettings', function (maxRows) {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, { fields: {'settings':1}});
    }
    this.ready();
});

//client side
Meteor.subscribe('userSettings');
```

But I do not see anyway how I can access the published "userSettings" object on the client side - what is missing ??

Answer (score 1):

You can create a field and set it to `false/''`, on each user you create using the [accountsOnCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) method.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  //this function gets called each time a user has been created on the Meteor.user collection
  if (options.profile)
    user.settings = ''; //this is just and example.
  return user;
})
```

Now the publish looks ok, but in order to get it work im always use a [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) function.

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('userSettings');
 })
```

*Why the autorun?* well if you don't call the auto run here, the subscription get only called 1 time when the apps loads, and not when the user documents.

Take care of yours deny/allow permissions, check this [meteor:common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) post on the **Profile editing** section

Also the subscribe function have a callback function.  `Meteor.subscribe(name, [arg1, arg2...], [callbacks])`, so you can do something like this.

```
var myUserSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('userSettings',function(){
 console.log("ok im here on the client side")
 console.log("this user subscription is ready " + myUserSubscription.ready())
})

console.log("outside the subscription why not? " + myUserSubscription.ready();
```

About [ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391308/custom-fields-on-meteor-users-not-being-published);

> True if the server has marked the subscription as ready. A reactive
>   data source.

Comment: Thank you Ethaan. How do I access the subscribed `userSettings` collection on the client side? Through `Meteor.user().settings` as usual (in which case what is the purpose of publish / subscribe).

Comment: by default only the `profile, username,email` got published by the client, any other field you want to publish on the client side, should be published on a publish function (damn so many times the publish word)

Comment: Cool - Thanks. So, if I understood correctly - `publish(userSettings,...)` will let the custom fields in the query to be published to client, but we still access those fields through `Meteor.user().customField` correct?

Comment: Yep like you access any normal object by .dot notation `Meteor.user().customField[0].firstField` supposing `customField` is an array