# Meteor only publishing Facebook Email, event with auto publish

Tags: facebook, meteor

I don't know what's gone wrong but my Meteor App isn't showing any of the User's Facebook data other than the email.

Even if its the User's own data and I've also tried adding auto publish but the data still doesnt show on the Client even though there is a lot more in the DB.

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}, {is_auto: true});

Meteor.publish('users', function() {

    if(this.userId) {
        if(Admins.find({admin: this.userId}).fetch().length > 0) {
            return Meteor.users.find();
        } else {
            return Meteor.users.find({}, {
                fields: {
                    'aboutMe': 1,
                    'profile.firstName': 1,
                    'profile.name': 1,
                    'profile.currentLocation': 1,
                    'profile.peerId':1,
                    'profile.profileType': 1,
                    'skills': 1,
                    'role': 1,
                    'education': 1,
                    'location': 1,
                    'currentLocation': 1,
                    'priceTier': 1,
                    'services.facebook.id': 1,
                    'services.facebook.first_name': 1,
                    'services.facebook.last_name': 1,
                    'services.facebook.gender': 1,
                    'createdAt': 1,
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {
            fields: {
                'emails': 0,
                'email': 0,
                'admin': 0,
                'approved': 0,
                'firstLogin': 0,
                'services.password': 0,
                'services.facebook.accessToken': 0,
                'services.facebook.email': 0,
                'registered_emails': 0,
                'profile.phone': 0
            }
       });
    }
});
```

I should be able to see all the info for at least the Current User but for every user all I can see from the services.facebook object is the email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom fields on Meteor.users not being published](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391308/custom-fields-on-meteor-users-not-being-published)

Comment: Nope, everything else works fine. I have different publications for a logged in user and non user and they work fine. Its just something with the services.facebook which return only the email address and nothing else from inside it.

Comment: But do you publish this data? If so, maybe edit your question with your publish function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added publication code to the question.