# Looking to set up default user profile data OnCreateUser

Tags: meteor

When a new user is created, I'd like to add a few attributes to the profile.  I do this in-app using a Collection update when the user changes settings, but can't seem to set defaults for new users when they sign up.

Here is my SERVER code:

```
userDefaults = (options, user) ->
    user.zipCode = 94582
    user.temperature = "Farenheit"
    user.city = "San Ramon"
    user.timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
    # Include the default profile info.
    user.profile = options.profile if options.profile
    console.log "added default #{options.profile} for #{user.profile}."
    user

Accounts.onCreateUser(userDefaults)
```

NOTE: The console log returns both options.profile and user.profile as undefined.

I also tried the below:

```
userDefaults = (options, user) ->
    user.profile = options.profile if options.profile
    user.profile.zipCode = 94582
    user.profile.temperature = "Farenheit"
    user.profile.city = "San Ramon"
    user.profile.timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
    console.log "added default #{options.profile} for #{user.profile}."
    user

Accounts.onCreateUser(userDefaults)
```

As profile isn't defined, I get this error: "Exception while invoking method 'createUser' TypeError: Cannot set property 'zipCode' of undefined"

Thanks for any assistance!!

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on SE: [Can't add user attribute using Accounts.onCreateUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605549/cant-add-user-attribute-using-accounts-oncreateuser)

It lit the way.  Here is my final working coffee code (server):

```
Accounts.onCreateUser( (options, user) ->
    options.profile = {} unless options.profile
    options.profile.zipCode = 94582
    options.profile.temperature = "Farenheit"
    options.profile.city = "San Ramon"
    options.profile.timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
    user.profile = options.profile if options.profile
    user)
```